# setinterval is not working when I use parameter in function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In javascript when I use parameter in function setInterval is not working

**Like**

```
 setInterval(function(){process(firs, seco)}, 1000);
```

**when I remove the parameters then it works like**

```
setInterval(function(){process()}, 1000);
```

function is

```
function process(firs, seco)
            {
                loadXMLDoc("submitmsg1.php?fir="+firs+"&sec="+seco ,function()
                {

                    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("showmsg").innerHTML= xhr.responseText;
                        }
                });
                }
```

I call this function here

```
<?php
    $fir = $_GET["fir"];
    $sec = $_GET["sec"];
?>

<body onload="process(<?php echo $fir; ?>, <?php echo $sec; ?>)">
    </body>
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I get no message only the setinterval do not works

Comment: Are the variables `firs` and `seco` defined anywhere?  *"I get no message"* Most likely you get a reference error, but just don't know where to look. [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to insert single quotes around the call to  like so:

```
process('<?php echo $fir; ?>', '<?php echo $sec; ?>')
```